The webpage created using WordPress and the Astra theme always loads incorrectly
I've built a website using WordPress with the Astra theme. Now I have an issue where every time I visit the homepage, one of the headings initially appears very large and then resizes to the correct smaller size. After analysis, I found that this might be related to a certain CSS file failing to load. This doesn't happen every time, but it does occur on the first visit. How should I handle this situation?


Caching can improve this. But failing to load files is big issue from server side so when cache is generated may break your website as will cache it with missing css files.
